# How can we decide FILLFACTOR of tables on production database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 E2 x64. on production machine having 8 core processor, 32 GB RAM.

My database is being used commonly for OLAP & OLTP both.

There are some constraints from Infra, "we can not change disk, RAID configuration and can't move database to another server.

tempdb, T-Logs & .mdf are located on seperate partition.

Then I thought to do, what may be possible at database end.

I retrived some information about indexes using below query.

Now the question is;-

1. Does proper FILLFACTOR value of Index helps to reduce disk IO?
2. If Yes, then how can we decide FILLFACTOR value based on the data I get using this query or Experts query (will be appreciated)?

   ```
   Select
               a.[Table Name],a.[Index Name],a.[Index Type],a.[Index Columns],a.[Row Count]
               ,ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,a.[Fill Factor],a.user_seeks,a.user_scans
               ,a.user_lookups,a.[Index Read],a.[Index Writes],a.[Last Used (Read)],a.[Last Used (Write)]
               ,[Last Index Re-Built/Re-Organize]
   from
   (select Top 10  t.name [Table Name]
               ,i.name [Index Name]
               ,i.type_desc [Index Type]
               ,c.name [Index Columns]
               ,p.rows [Row Count]
               ,i.fill_factor [Fill Factor]
               ,ius.user_seeks
               ,ius.user_scans
               ,ius.user_lookups
               ,(ius.user_seeks+ius.user_scans+ius.user_lookups) [Index Read]
               ,ius.user_updates [Index Writes]
               ,COALESCE(ius.last_user_seek,ius.last_user_scan,ius.last_user_lookup) [Last Used (Read)]
               ,ius.last_user_update [Last Used (Write)]
               ,STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id) [Last Index Re-Built/Re-Organize]
               ,i.index_id
               ,t.object_id

   from        sys.tables t
   inner join  sys.columns c
   on          t.object_id=c.object_id
   inner join  sys.indexes i
   on          t.object_id=i.object_id
   inner join  sys.index_columns ic
   on          t.object_id=ic.object_id and i.index_id=ic.index_id and c.column_id=ic.column_id
   inner join  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius
   on          t.object_id=ius.object_id and i.index_id=ius.index_id
   inner join  sys.stats s
   on          t.object_id=s.object_id and i.index_id=s.stats_id
   inner join  sys.partitions p
   on          p.object_id=i.object_id and p.index_id=i.index_id
   Order by ius.user_lookups desc  -- Use to see by CPU, Resd, Writes, No. of Records.
   ) a
   cross apply
               sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),a.object_id,a.index_id,0,DEFAULT) ips
   ```

Comment: Are you facing any performance issue ?. How did you reach to conclusion that current fill factor is bad.There is no absolute formula for Fill factor calculation

Comment: Yes, I am facing IO overhead on disk & some time it's 100% (using Idera Diagnostics Manager) on the .mdf file partition. It's not conclusion to modify FILLFACTOR only. If you have any suggestion apart from that according to my query, I will try that.

Comment: Yes if you have too low fill factor value there would be lot of wasted free space in database page and so more I/O and memory would be required to bring pages into memory.

Comment: Fillfactor parameter is really effective only just after index is rebuilt. Sql server doen't use fillfactor when it’s allocating a new index page. You may try lowering fillfactor on highly volatile tables gradually, by 5% for example at every index rebuild and see if it helps.

Comment: @Serge Size of my table is 2 TB, we receive 65 GB/day. We do have staging env. but transaction ration with compare to production is very low, so I will try it on staging, but can't take risk if it does not perform well on production.

Comment: When one table is 2tb and you have 32gb of RAM you will likely spend most of your time hitting disk. Instead of messing with fill factor, buy more RAM.

Comment: Yes adding more RAM may help me out and there is limit, can we do somthing at SQL Server end apart from that..

Comment: With a table that large, most likely you should think about remodeling the table. Easier said than done, but would be more effective than worrying about `FILLFACTOR`. And most likely lowering `FILLFACTOR` below 100 will have a very negative impact on performance since it is doubtful you are getting page splits on even 50% of those pages.